# mysql-connector issue while executing program(bad handshake)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

> I am getting some bad handshake errors while execution of program
> after installing mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector as c
con=c.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd='tiger',database='employee')
if con.is_connected():
    print("success")
else:
    print("connectivity issue")
```

> errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sahil Panhalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 268, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Bad handshake

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sahil Panhalkar\Desktop\connectivity.py", line 2, in <module>
    con=c.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd='tiger',database='employee')
  File "C:\Users\Sahil Panhalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 286, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sahil Panhalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sahil Panhalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1108, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Sahil Panhalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 273, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake
```